# Why am I getting these symbols in console, using printf()?

Tags: c++, string, printf, scanf, undefined-behavior

I have question about output in console

```
string str;
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", str);
```

Why do I get strange symbols, which have trouble with encoding?

Comment: Possibly not this, but wouldn't `printf` expect a c string i.e. `char*`? Same with `scanf`. Also why use `printf` and `scanf` instead `std::cout` and `std::cin`?

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is a class (user-defined type). On the other hand, the conversion specifier `s` is designed to input or output character arrays. So the code snippet has undefined behavior.

Instead you could use operators >> and << overloaded for the class `std::string` to input or output data from/to streams like

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
std::cout << str << '\n';
```

If you want to use the functions scanf and printf then use character arrays as for example

```
char str[100];

scanf( "%99s", str );
printf( "%s\n", str );
```

If as you wrote in a comment

> I have a task, out string with help printf.

then in this case you should check whether `string` is indeed the standard C++ type or an alias for the type `char *` introduced like for example

```
typedef char *string;
```

or like

```
using string = char *;
```

Comment: I have a task, out string with help printf. Do you know how do it?

Comment: @user18999150 You shall not use objects of the type std::string with scanf or printf though there is a possibility to output an object of the type std::string using printf for example the following way  printf( "%s\n", str.c_str() ); or printf( "%s\n", str.data() );

Comment: @Klaus nitpick _than_ isn't the same as _then_.

Comment: @user18999150 I suspect that they mean an alias of the type char * as I wrote in my answer.:) Or they just refer to C strings using the word string.

Comment: @Klaus it's not a _"stupid task"_ at all. It makes you familiar how to interact with legacy c-libraries you cannot change, and have to use these in your daily, bread and butter, payed real world production code.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and `scanf` expect variables of type [const] `char *` with an "%s" format specifier.

In general, the [other answer to use `std::cin` / `std::cout` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72067171) is preferrable.

If you absolutely must use `printf` to output a `std::string`, use the `c_str()` method to get access to a `const char *` representing the same string as in the `std::string`; example:

```
string str;
std::cin >> str;
printf("%s", str.c_str());
```

Note the [`const` in `const char* c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)  - meaning you are not allowed to change the returned string. So, it cannot be used for `scanf`.  There, you'd have to stick to a `char *`...

Comment: In such an answer I expect at minimum that such coding should be avoided! Use C or C++... If someone gives such a task... there must be a very good reason for this! Teaching bad style should not be one of them...